# How do we fix this diagram with sets, crosses and arrows involving tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

Using [Matcha.io](https://www.mathcha.io/), I created a diagram:

[image]

However, when I exported into `tikz` and pasted this into a latex file:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,271); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 271

%Straight Lines [id:da1549095426079492] 
\draw    (143,118) -- (143,138) ;
\draw [shift={(143,140)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da04787243179276457] 
\draw    (144,158) -- (144,177) ;
\draw [shift={(144,179)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7069336627624474] 
\draw    (168,117) -- (168,138) ;
\draw [shift={(168,140)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7734512305857542] 
\draw    (169,158) -- (169,178) ;
\draw [shift={(169,180)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7092550637871353] 
\draw    (198,117) -- (198,138) ;
\draw [shift={(198,140)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8430150592615393] 
\draw    (197,157) -- (197,178) ;
\draw [shift={(197,180)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da49713009947789355] 
\draw    (222,118) -- (222,139) ;
\draw [shift={(222,141)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6546765869083959] 
\draw    (222,159) -- (222,180) ;
\draw [shift={(222,182)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da47385102274510715] 
\draw    (250,118) -- (250,139) ;
\draw [shift={(250,141)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da06659798425033858] 
\draw    (251,159) -- (251,180) ;
\draw [shift={(251,182)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da10973808804743945] 
\draw    (280,118) -- (280,139) ;
\draw [shift={(280,141)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6384616526222531] 
\draw    (280,157) -- (280,178) ;
\draw [shift={(280,180)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8996600154832433] 
\draw    (304,117) -- (304,138) ;
\draw [shift={(304,140)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da01779530027009435] 
\draw    (305,156) -- (305,177) ;
\draw [shift={(305,179)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9199192365146485] 
\draw    (213,148) -- (232,148.5) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4394451197248137] 
\draw    (214,192) -- (233,192.5) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5379498648849983] 
\draw    (214,105) -- (233,105.5) ;

% Text Node
\draw (106,181.41) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [rotate=-359.99]  {$I=\{1\ ,\ 2\ ,\ \ 3,\ \ 4,\ \ \ 5,\ \ \ 6,\ \ 7\}$};
% Text Node
\draw (99,139.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$R=\{1,\ \ 2,\ \ \ 1,\ \ 4,\ \ \ 3,\ \ \ 1,\ \ 1\}$};
% Text Node
\draw (120,92.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\left\{\text{P1} ,\text{P2} ,\ \text{P3} ,\text{P4} ,\ \text{P5} ,\text{P6} ,\text{P7}\right\}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image]

**Question:** How do we fix the code?

Comment: We don't fix the code. We create the diagram (table?) from scratch. Should the arrows be strictly vertical? This looks like a job for a TikZ matrix, a NiceMatrix or normal array with tikzmark.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, the arrows should be strictly vertical.

Comment: The problem here is that matcha.io is simply a graphic tool. It has no idea of semantic, that is, meaning of the diagram. Writing that directly in LaTeX will force you to describe the meaning. I would try something with tabularray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following TikZ-CD environment

- doesn't use math mode for the first row's nodes,
- right aligns the first column,
- has no `inner xsep` for its nodes and no `text depth` (makes horizontal spacing easier and vertical arrows have the same length),
- has a `column sep` that makes it so that the columns are spaced as if it were just a comma separated list,
- provides a few shortcuts:

  - `\c` for a comma that doesn't change how the arrows are aligned,
  - `\LB` for the left brace and
  - `\RB` for the right brace.

  These all will typeset their content without changing the position of the nodes but also don't update the TikZ diagram's bounding box (but we can ignore this here)
- and a `cross out` style to be used on the nodes that should be crossed out.

It also includes a arrow tip specification that is closer to those of XY packages (which would be similar to those of your sketches) but I'm not using it.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\makeatletter
\tikzcdset{diagrams={% this will allow math mode to be deselected
    /tikz/matrix of math nodes/.style={
      /tikz/matrix of nodes,
      /tikz/nodes={
        execute at begin node=\iftikzcd@mathmode$\fi,
        execute at end node=\iftikzcd@mathmode$\fi}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  /tikz/cross out/.style={
    append after command=(\tikzlastnode.west) edge (\tikzlastnode.east)},
  /tikz/row 1/.append style={commutative diagrams/math mode=false},
  /tikz/column 1/.append style={anchor=base east},
  cells={inner xsep=+0pt, text depth=+0pt},
  row sep=.7em, column sep=width("{,\space}"),
%  tikzcd to/.tip={To[length=+3pt +2.5, width=+2pt +2.5]},
  /utils/exec=
    \renewcommand*\c{\rlap{,}}%
    \newcommand*\LB{\smash{\llap{\{}}}%
    \newcommand*\RB{\unskip\smash{\rlap{\}}}},
]
      & \LB P1\c \dar & P2\c \dar & P3\c  \dar &|[cross out]| P4\c \dar
      &     P5\c \dar & P6\c \dar & P7\RB \dar \\
  R = & \LB 1\c  \dar & 2\c  \dar & 1\c  \dar  & |[cross out]| 4\c \dar
      &     3\c \dar  & 1\c  \dar & 1\RB \dar \\
  I = & \LB 1\c       & 2\c       & 3\c        & |[cross out]| 4\c 
      &     5\c       & 6\c       & 7\RB
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]